# What prevents page migration?

Tags: linux, memory, cache, numa

OpenSUSE 42.3, Kernel 4.4.175-89-default

Running memory bandwidth intensive applications I realised the following behaviour:
The application uses ~55% of the physical memory of a NUMA system with 2 nodes. The application is parallelized using OpenMP, but without accounting for NUMA. So it relies on page migration to achieve a somewhat decent execution speed.

Here is how that looks like:
[image: Wall time per iteration]

At around 180 iterations, I cleared caches manually using

```
# echo 3 >| /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

The result is an immediate performance improvement.
What prevents the system from doing proper page migration before I cleared the caches manually?

Comment: have you ever figured this out?